# go sms pro and android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED receiver

Tags: android

i was reading sms with broadcast receiver like:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
...
}
```

but now i install `go sms pro` and my receiver is never fired again. Why? How can i still fire my receiver even if i am using go sms pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in manifest, where you declare your intent listener. Add:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">
```

GoSMSPro has higher priority then your listener most likely

Answer (score 0):

go sms pro has set these lines in it's manifest for SmsReceiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".smspopup.SmsReceiver"     android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.GSM_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.mms.transaction.MESSAGE_SENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

all these intent-filters make its priority higher than your receiver even if your reciever has the priority set to 2147483647. you can see the list of all receivers of all apps by:

```
List<ResolveInfo> receivers = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"), 0);
```

the first receiver in the list, receives the sms before than others